# Right syntax SPARQL query from dbpedia.org

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am new to RDF and SPARQL and am struggling with what syntax is correct. When I look up examples on the web, it looks fairly easy, but when I try to apply it and do exercises, it simply doesn't work.

Currently I have to make a list with three columns, containing the European Union countries, population size (ranked from big to small), and the type of government the country has.

I have tried a number of PREFIX's and practically every imaginable text (See below), but nothing works.

```
PREFIX dbc: <dbc:Member_states_of_the_European_Union>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/Country>

SELECT ?populationsize
WHERE
{
?populationsize dbo:populationTotal ?number
}
```

Comment: You might start with [the actual SPARQL documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/). I think you're misunderstanding what `PREFIX` does, among other things. (As this also looks like homework, you might recheck whatever docs the instructor provided.)

Answer (score 1):

Personally,  this is still very unclear to me, but this works!

```
PREFIX  dbo:  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX  yago: <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/>
PREFIX  dbp:  <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX  dct:  <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>

SELECT DISTINCT  *
WHERE
{ ?country  dct:subject  
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Member_states_of_the_European_Union> ;
          dbo:populationTotal  ?populationTotal;
          dbo:governmentType  ?governmentType
}

ORDER BY DESC(?populationTotal)
```

Comment: why is this unclear resp. what? in your question, the query has just one variable after the select, thus, you get just a single "column" back. RDF -> graph <- SPARQL (graph pattern matching)

Answer (score 1):

Note that [your revised query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51294843/241164) doesn't use, and so you don't need to include, the `yago:` nor `dct:` prefixes.  I've also added another prefix, for the Category.

```
PREFIX  dbc:  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:>
PREFIX  dbo:  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX  dct:  <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>

SELECT DISTINCT  *
WHERE
{ ?country  dct:subject          dbc:Member_states_of_the_European_Union ;
            dbo:populationTotal  ?populationTotal ;
            dbo:governmentType   ?governmentType
}
ORDER BY DESC(?populationTotal)
```

That's the same query as this, with no `PREFIX` at all --

```
SELECT DISTINCT  *
WHERE
{ ?country  http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject             http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Member_states_of_the_European_Union ;
            http://dbpedia.org/ontology/populationTotal  ?populationTotal ;
            http://dbpedia.org/ontology/governmentType   ?governmentType
}
ORDER BY DESC(?populationTotal)
```

The labels you want are just an attribute of the URIs currently being retrieved.  Labels exist in multiple languages, so I've added a `FILTER` here to get only the labels tagged as English.

```
PREFIX  dbc:  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:>
PREFIX  dbo:  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX  dct:  <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>

SELECT DISTINCT  *
WHERE
{ ?country  dct:subject          dbc:Member_states_of_the_European_Union ;
            dbo:populationTotal  ?populationTotal ;
            dbo:governmentType   ?governmentType .
  OPTIONAL  { ?country         rdfs:label  ?countryLabel  .
              FILTER ( lang(?countryLabel)="en" ) }
  OPTIONAL  { ?governmentType  rdfs:label  ?governmentTypeLabel  .
              FILTER ( lang(?governmentTypeLabel)="en" ) }
}
ORDER BY DESC(?populationTotal)
```

I know you don't want the literal types nor langtags, so here's one more tweak to make all the output simple --

```
PREFIX  dbc:  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:>
PREFIX  dbo:  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX  dct:  <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>

SELECT DISTINCT  ( STR(?populationTotal)     AS ?Population )
                 ( STR(?countryLabel)        AS ?Country )
                 ( STR(?governmentTypeLabel) AS ?Government )
WHERE
{ ?country  dct:subject          dbc:Member_states_of_the_European_Union ;
            dbo:populationTotal  ?populationTotal ;
            dbo:governmentType   ?governmentType .
  OPTIONAL  { ?country  rdfs:label  ?countryLabel  .
                FILTER ( LANG(?countryLabel) = "en" ) }
  OPTIONAL  { ?governmentType  rdfs:label  ?governmentTypeLabel  .
                FILTER ( LANG(?governmentTypeLabel) = "en" ) }
}
ORDER BY DESC(?populationTotal)
```

Comment: Awesome! thank you :) Any clue how I can retrieve the lables instead of the sourcecode? If you run this now, it show's the entire URL instead of just the countries, their population size and their type of government...

Comment: RDF doesn't involve tables; it involves a graph. The output of these queries is not "sourcecode"; it's a serialization of exactly the data you've requested. If you want the labels associated with URIs, or you want simple literals instead the typed-literals, you need to specify such...  I'll try to update my answer in the next day or two.

Comment: That would be absolutely amazing! I could not figure out how to get the labels

Comment: I've updated my answer.  If you need more help, it's time for a new, focused question.

Comment: The code above only works without the three PREFIX's, thank you very much for your time! I'll study this thoroughly :)

Comment: Ah, sorry, SO decorates `<pre>` tagged content as code, but doesn't fully preserve it -- so `<wrapped>` things disappear. SPARQL isn't complete without PREFIX declarations for all prefixes used within the query. The three I chose are pre-defined on the DBpedia endpoint, but cannot be assumed elsewhere, and may not always be defined as they are today -- so I've fixed the "markdown" markup on the latter queries, and you should be able to copy-and-paste any of them now.

Comment: Excellent! thanks again, really appreciate it :)! any recommendations on where to find info about SPARQL and RDF etc?

Comment: [Understanding Data presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/kidehen/understanding-29894555/), [SPARQL spec docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-overview/), [RDF spec docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-primer/), Google and other search engines (try `info about SPARQL and RDF`)...